# UITableViewSection checkmark

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, static

I have a static tableview controller, it has 4 sections, the other 3 sections go into another view to select data and pass it back to the Label on them, but I have one section here that I want to (only two options) have them select directly on the screen and display a checkmark, also want to be able to reference that selection of the label back for data storage, instead of having another screen with only 2 options on it.

I'm not sure exactly how I would integrate the didSelectRow with the Sections, to make sure it does not affect my other static cells that are segues to another screen.

Any recommendations? (PS I'm new to Swift)

Thanks!

Comment: `if indexPath.section == 2 { // change checkmark }`?!

Comment: It's probably a good idea to use dynamic cells for this